# Link in description in manifest.json for Teams app

Tags: microsoft-teams

I create the Teams app. I want to put the link in the link in the description. Is it possible? I try to surrounds link with [a]link[/a] and with link, both option are escaped.

Answer (score 1):

The description field supports simple markdown syntax. I haven't tried a link, but you can easily test it your side. Please see here for details on links and other markdown syntax: https://www.markdownguide.org/cheat-sheet/